# Best way to scrape a list of data from a website with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I'm scraping data from a web page for use in an API and looking for the most pythonic / appropriate way to do it - The page source has a list of dictionaries titled 'markerData' and I need to grab the lat and lng values.

Data Sample:

> "markerData":
>   [{"docEl":null,"lid":0,"clickable":true,"lat":34.0489281,"lng":-111.0937311,"title":"","iconURL":"//assets.bankofamerica.com/images/mapmarker2.png","info":"</div>View all locations in
>   Arizona</a></div></div></div></div></div>"},
>   {"docEl":null,"lid":1,"clickable":true,"lat":35.20105,"lng":-91.8318334,"title":"","iconURL":"//assets.bankofamerica.com/images/mapmarker2.png","info":"</div>View all locations in
>   Arkansas</a></div></div></div></div></div>"},

I've used python's lxml module a few times in the past for this kind of task, however seeing as my 'markerData' isn't an obvious html structure I'm trying to figure out the best way to proceed. Specifically, in the function below, I am stuck attempting to define the tree.xpath for each of my lat and lng values.

```
lats = []
lngs = []

def get_coordinates():

    i = 0

    while i < 35:

            page = requests.get('https://locators.bankofamerica.com/&check_list=4429#')
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

            lat = tree.xpath('//div[@id=mapWrap/markerData/lat/text()'.format(i))
            lng = tree.xpath('//div[@id=mapWrap/markerData/lng/text()'.format(i))

            str1 = ''.join(lat)
            str2 = ''.join(lng)

            lats.append(str1)
            lngs.append(str2)

            i += 1

    return lats, lngs
```

I also can't fight the feeling there might be an easier way to do this such as reading the entire page-source into a text file and trying to grab just the 'markerData' list.

I would appreciate any help in defining an xpath for my lat and lng values, or any alternative ideas on how to isolate and capture this data.

Comment: Beautifulsoup would probably work better.

Comment: That looks like json, you should use that to parse.

Comment: `markerData` appears to be embedded in Javascript, which may require Selenium or PhantomJS

Comment: Or the dryscrape library. If you have chrome, you could inpect, right click on the element, and copy xpath.

Comment: For starters, don't use a while-loop, use a for-loop.

Comment: @davedwards Indeed it is embedded js. Is there a selenium library for data parsing that I don't know about ? I've used python with selenium exclusively for UI testing. Thanks for the tip. EDIT: I think you mean get the xpath using selenium (by clicking) - I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the function I wrote that got the job done for me in case it might help someone else in a similar situation:

```
def get_coordinates():

        page = requests.get('https://locators.bankofamerica.com/&check_list=4429')
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

        lat_lng = tree.xpath("//script[contains(., 'markerData')]/text()")
        lat_lng_string = str(lat_lng)
        latitude = re.findall('"lat":\d+\.\d+', lat_lng_string)
        longitude = re.findall('"lng":-\d+\.\d+', lat_lng_string)

        la = re.findall('\d+\.\d+', str(latitude))
        lo = re.findall('-\d+\.\d+', str(longitude))

        coords = dict(zip(la, lo))

        return coords
```